# Colourbox and timthumb.php

Tags: php, lightbox

I am having issues with timthumb.php and colourbox lightbox, timthumb is working great on everything else but when i try to load a larger image i get the following

[image]

The images just shows as code really need help???

here is my code.

```
if ($handle = opendir('./users/2/images')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {


        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            if(preg_match("/\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|JPG)$/i", $entry)) {

            $file = site_url() . "/users/2/images/$entry";

            $removeLink = "users/2/images/$entry";

          echo '<li><a class="group1" href="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/timthumb.php?src='.$file.'&h=500&q=80&webshot=1"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/timthumb.php?src='.$file.'&h=80&zc=1"  onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\'" /></a><a href="'.$file.'" rel="nofollow">Download</a><a class="imageSort" href="" id="'.$removeLink.'" title="images">drag me</a><a href="'.$file.'" rel="nofollow">View Raw</a></li>';      

            } 
        } 
    }
    closedir($handle);
```

has anyone had similar issues???

bump anyone got and suggestions with this???

```
<?php
/**
 * TimThumb by Ben Gillbanks and Mark Maunder
 * Based on work done by Tim McDaniels and Darren Hoyt
 * http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/
 * 
 * GNU General Public License, version 2
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Examples and documentation available on the project homepage
 * http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/
 */

/*
    -----TimThumb CONFIGURATION-----
    You can either edit the configuration variables manually here, or you can 
    create a file called timthumb-config.php and define variables you want
    to customize in there. It will automatically be loaded by timthumb.
    This will save you having to re-edit these variables everytime you download
    a new version of timthumb.

*/
define ('VERSION', '2.8.2');                                        // Version of this script 
//Load a config file if it exists. Otherwise, use the values below
if( file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/timthumb-config.php'))    require_once('timthumb-config.php');
if(! defined('DEBUG_ON') )          define ('DEBUG_ON', TRUE);              // Enable debug logging to web server error log (STDERR)
if(! defined('DEBUG_LEVEL') )           define ('DEBUG_LEVEL', 1);              // Debug level 1 is less noisy and 3 is the most noisy
if(! defined('MEMORY_LIMIT') )          define ('MEMORY_LIMIT', '30M');             // Set PHP memory limit
if(! defined('BLOCK_EXTERNAL_LEECHERS') )   define ('BLOCK_EXTERNAL_LEECHERS', TRUE);       // If the image or webshot is being loaded on an external site, display a red "No Hotlinking" gif.

//Image fetching and caching
if(! defined('ALLOW_EXTERNAL') )        define ('ALLOW_EXTERNAL', TRUE);            // Allow image fetching from external websites. Will check against ALLOWED_SITES if ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES is false
if(! defined('ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES') )  define ('ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES', TRUE);      // Less secure. 
if(! defined('FILE_CACHE_ENABLED') )        define ('FILE_CACHE_ENABLED', TRUE);            // Should we store resized/modified images on disk to speed things up?
if(! defined('FILE_CACHE_TIME_BETWEEN_CLEANS')) define ('FILE_CACHE_TIME_BETWEEN_CLEANS', 86400);   // How often the cache is cleaned 
if(! defined('FILE_CACHE_MAX_FILE_AGE') )   define ('FILE_CACHE_MAX_FILE_AGE', 86400);      // How old does a file have to be to be deleted from the cache
if(! defined('FILE_CACHE_SUFFIX') )         define ('FILE_CACHE_SUFFIX', '.timthumb.txt');      // What to put at the end of all files in the cache directory so we can identify them
if(! defined('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY') )      define ('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY', './cache');     // Directory where images are cached. Left blank it will use the system temporary directory (which is better for security)
if(! defined('MAX_FILE_SIZE') )         define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 10485760);         // 10 Megs is 10485760. This is the max internal or external file size that we'll process.  
if(! defined('CURL_TIMEOUT') )          define ('CURL_TIMEOUT', 20);                // Timeout duration for Curl. This only applies if you have Curl installed and aren't using PHP's default URL fetching mechanism.
if(! defined('WAIT_BETWEEN_FETCH_ERRORS') )     define ('WAIT_BETWEEN_FETCH_ERRORS', 3600);     //Time to wait between errors fetching remote file
//Browser caching
if(! defined('BROWSER_CACHE_MAX_AGE') )     define ('BROWSER_CACHE_MAX_AGE', 864000);       // Time to cache in the browser
if(! defined('BROWSER_CACHE_DISABLE') )     define ('BROWSER_CACHE_DISABLE', false);        // Use for testing if you want to disable all browser caching

//Image size and defaults
if(! defined('MAX_WIDTH') )             define ('MAX_WIDTH', 1500);             // Maximum image width
if(! defined('MAX_HEIGHT') )            define ('MAX_HEIGHT', 1500);                // Maximum image height
if(! defined('NOT_FOUND_IMAGE') )       define ('NOT_FOUND_IMAGE', '');             //Image to serve if any 404 occurs 
if(! defined('ERROR_IMAGE') )           define ('ERROR_IMAGE', '');             //Image to serve if an error occurs instead of showing error message 

//Image compression is enabled if either of these point to valid paths

//These are now disabled by default because the file sizes of PNGs (and GIFs) are much smaller than we used to generate. 
//They only work for PNGs. GIFs and JPEGs are not affected.
if(! defined('OPTIPNG_ENABLED') )       define ('OPTIPNG_ENABLED', false);  
if(! defined('OPTIPNG_PATH') )          define ('OPTIPNG_PATH', '/usr/bin/optipng'); //This will run first because it gives better compression than pngcrush. 
if(! defined('PNGCRUSH_ENABLED') )      define ('PNGCRUSH_ENABLED', false); 
if(! defined('PNGCRUSH_PATH') )         define ('PNGCRUSH_PATH', '/usr/bin/pngcrush'); //This will only run if OPTIPNG_PATH is not set or is not valid

/*
    -------====Website Screenshots configuration - BETA====-------

    If you just want image thumbnails and don't want website screenshots, you can safely leave this as is.  

    If you would like to get website screenshots set up, you will need root access to your own server.

    Enable ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES so you can fetch any external web page. This is more secure now that we're using a non-web folder for cache.
    Enable BLOCK_EXTERNAL_LEECHERS so that your site doesn't generate thumbnails for the whole Internet.

    Instructions to get website screenshots enabled on Ubuntu Linux:

    1. Install Xvfb with the following command: sudo apt-get install subversion libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev g++ xvfb
    2. Go to a directory where you can download some code
    3. Check-out the latest version of CutyCapt with the following command: svn co https://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cutycapt
    4. Compile CutyCapt by doing: cd cutycapt/CutyCapt
    5. qmake
    6. make
    7. cp CutyCapt /usr/local/bin/
    8. Test it by running: xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" CutyCapt --url="http://markmaunder.com/" --out=test.png
    9. If you get a file called test.png with something in it, it probably worked. Now test the script by accessing it as follows:
    10. http://yoursite.com/path/to/timthumb.php?src=http://markmaunder.com/&webshot=1

    Notes on performance: 
    The first time a webshot loads, it will take a few seconds.
    From then on it uses the regular timthumb caching mechanism with the configurable options above
    and loading will be very fast.

    --ADVANCED USERS ONLY--
    If you'd like a slight speedup (about 25%) and you know Linux, you can run the following command which will keep Xvfb running in the background.
    nohup Xvfb :100 -ac -nolisten tcp -screen 0, 1024x768x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    Then set WEBSHOT_XVFB_RUNNING = true below. This will save your server having to fire off a new Xvfb server and shut it down every time a new shot is generated. 
    You will need to take responsibility for keeping Xvfb running in case it crashes. (It seems pretty stable)
    You will also need to take responsibility for server security if you're running Xvfb as root. 


*/
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_ENABLED') )   define ('WEBSHOT_ENABLED', false);          //Beta feature. Adding webshot=1 to your query string will cause the script to return a browser screenshot rather than try to fetch an image.
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_CUTYCAPT') )  define ('WEBSHOT_CUTYCAPT', '/usr/local/bin/CutyCapt'); //The path to CutyCapt. 
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_XVFB') )      define ('WEBSHOT_XVFB', '/usr/bin/xvfb-run');       //The path to the Xvfb server
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_SCREEN_X') )  define ('WEBSHOT_SCREEN_X', '1024');            //1024 works ok
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_SCREEN_Y') )  define ('WEBSHOT_SCREEN_Y', '768');         //768 works ok
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_COLOR_DEPTH') )   define ('WEBSHOT_COLOR_DEPTH', '24');           //I haven't tested anything besides 24
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_IMAGE_FORMAT') )  define ('WEBSHOT_IMAGE_FORMAT', 'png');         //png is about 2.5 times the size of jpg but is a LOT better quality
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_TIMEOUT') )   define ('WEBSHOT_TIMEOUT', '20');           //Seconds to wait for a webshot
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_USER_AGENT') )    define ('WEBSHOT_USER_AGENT', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18"); //I hate to do this, but a non-browser robot user agent might not show what humans see. So we pretend to be Firefox
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_JAVASCRIPT_ON') ) define ('WEBSHOT_JAVASCRIPT_ON', true);         //Setting to false might give you a slight speedup and block ads. But it could cause other issues.
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_JAVA_ON') )   define ('WEBSHOT_JAVA_ON', false);          //Have only tested this as fase
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_PLUGINS_ON') )    define ('WEBSHOT_PLUGINS_ON', true);            //Enable flash and other plugins
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_PROXY') )     define ('WEBSHOT_PROXY', '');               //In case you're behind a proxy server. 
if(! defined('WEBSHOT_XVFB_RUNNING') )  define ('WEBSHOT_XVFB_RUNNING', false);         //ADVANCED: Enable this if you've got Xvfb running in the background.


// If ALLOW_EXTERNAL is true and ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES is false, then external images will only be fetched from these domains and their subdomains. 
if(! isset($ALLOWED_SITES)){
    $ALLOWED_SITES = array (
        'flickr.com',
        'picasa.com',
        'img.youtube.com',
        'upload.wikimedia.org',
        'photobucket.com',
        'imgur.com',
        'imageshack.us',
        'tinypic.com',
        'ongmat.cz',
        'justimages.users37.interdns.co.uk',
    );
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
// -------------- STOP EDITING CONFIGURATION HERE --------------
// -------------------------------------------------------------

timthumb::start();

class timthumb {

}
```

Comment: Where is the colorbox code? Maybe provide us with the full page source code.

Comment: hi evan the coloubox code i am using is this $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1', transition:"none", width:"55%", height:"55%"});

Comment: You mentioned it was just on the larger image files? Is it possible your hosting has some kind of restriction? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: hi evan yes i thought that i contacted my hosting and they said nothing has changed with the gd library, it does just seem to happen on certain images large ones in general, but this isnt great for me as it kind off defeats the point of what i am trying to achieve. thanks for the response.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use `photo: true` in ColorBox params.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and this fixed it. U rock

Answer (score 0):

//timthumb.php
Makse sure you have a header entry like the following :

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: hi mathboy i have tried that but still doesnt seem to be working <?php header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
define ('VERSION', '2.8.2');          // Version of this script 
//Load a config file if it exists. Otherwise, use the values below
if( file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/timthumb-config.php')) require_once('timthumb-config.php');

Comment: Can you post the source code of timthumb.php formatted in your question ?

Comment: hi mathboy i have pasted the timthumb code that i am using above i left out the actually class as that shouldn't change and was limited to characters.

Comment: Seems like the output has been corrupted in somewhere , but the question is , why you need all of these configurations and  codes ? if you want to display the image with a specific dimensions and quality , you can do it easily with a small amount of coding !